# Preserving state of Checkboxes while paging in ASP.Net GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i'm using gridview for paging data from sql server database and if i change the gridview page the checkbox that i check doesn't maintain the state after i checked it. here is my code :

```
    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim cls As New clsMain
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    strSQL = "SELECT * from tbldata"
    ds = cls.ReturnDataSet(strSQL)



    gvTF.AllowPaging = True
    gvTF.DataSource() = ds
    gvTF.DataBind()

    Dim CheckBoxArray As ArrayList
    If ViewState("CheckBoxArray") IsNot Nothing Then
        CheckBoxArray = TryCast(ViewState("CheckBoxArray"), ArrayList)
    Else
        CheckBoxArray = New ArrayList()
    End If

    If IsPostBack Then
        Dim CheckBoxIndex As Integer
        Dim CheckAllWasChecked As Boolean = False
        Dim chkAll As CheckBox = TryCast(gvTF.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("checkAll"), CheckBox)

        Dim checkAllIndex As String = "checkAll-" & gvTF.PageIndex

        If chkAll.Checked Then
            If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) = -1 Then
                CheckBoxArray.Add(checkAllIndex)
            End If
        Else
            If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) <> -1 Then
                CheckBoxArray.Remove(checkAllIndex)
                CheckAllWasChecked = True
            End If
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To gvTF.Rows.Count - 1
            If gvTF.Rows(i).RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim chk As CheckBox = _
                 DirectCast(gvTF.Rows(i).Cells(0) _
                 .FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)
                CheckBoxIndex = gvTF.PageSize * gvTF.PageIndex + (i + 1)
                If chk.Checked Then
                    If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) = -1 And _
                        Not CheckAllWasChecked Then
                        CheckBoxArray.Add(CheckBoxIndex)
                    End If
                Else
                    If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) <> -1 Or _
                        CheckAllWasChecked Then
                        CheckBoxArray.Remove(CheckBoxIndex)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    ViewState("CheckBoxArray") = CheckBoxArray
```

and here the code when i'm changing the page :

```
   Protected Sub OnPaging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    gvTF.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    gvTF.DataBind()
    If ViewState("CheckBoxArray") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim CheckBoxArray As ArrayList = _
        DirectCast(ViewState("CheckBoxArray"), ArrayList)
        Dim checkAllIndex As String = "checkAll-" & gvTF.PageIndex

        If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) <> -1 Then
            Dim chkAll As CheckBox = _
            DirectCast(gvTF.HeaderRow.Cells(0) _
            .FindControl("checkAll"), CheckBox)
            chkAll.Checked = True
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To gvTF.Rows.Count - 1
            If gvTF.Rows(i).RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) <> -1 Then
                    Dim chk As CheckBox = _
                    DirectCast(gvTF.Rows(i).Cells(0) _
                    .FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)
                    chk.Checked = True
                    gvTF.Rows(i).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:aqua")
                Else
                    Dim CheckBoxIndex As Integer = gvTF.PageSize * (gvTF.PageIndex) + (i + 1)
                    If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) <> -1 Then
                        Dim chk As CheckBox = _
                        DirectCast(gvTF.Rows(i).Cells(0) _
                        .FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)
                        chk.Checked = True
                        gvTF.Rows(i).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:aqua")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A  paged GridView only renders the current page's data to the markup, so when trying to loop through its rows then it will only return the available rows that are displayed on the current paged data.
However, you could use other methods to address the issue, [Like Bind GridView with Paging using jQuery](https://www.yogihosting.com/bind-gridview-with-ajax/) 
OR
[Enable Sorting And Paging Callbacks](https://forums.asp.net/t/1866383.aspx?Gridview%20paging%20without%20postback)

Comment: Please edit relevant content into your answer, rather than relying on external links that may become stale or inaccessible in the future.